# How to define a matrix of Graphics in VBA?

Tags: vba, graphics

I am building a program with VBA and on it I use Graphic to fill a bitmap picture and show it in a picture box this Graphic must change with time.

Because there are lots of calculation for update Graphic on each time step it just don't work well and have a time lag after a while as calculations begin to expand.

So, can I define a matrix of Graphics and set them before showing it and when it is playing I just change root Graphic in each time step?

I tried to define a matrix of graphics like this:

```
 Dim my_graph(360) As Graphics
```

and in Set_Graph function i formed the my_graph(i) by drawing lines, points, etc

```
Set_Graph(my_graph(i), w, t, b, POINTS_x, POINTS_y)
my_graph(i) = Graphics.FromImage(My_Bitmap)
PICTURE_BOX_2.Image = My_Bitmap
```

But in Set_Graph, my_graph(i) is null and nothing.It works when i use one Graphics:

```
Dim my_graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(My_Bitmap)
Set_Graph(my_graph, w, t, b, POINTS_x, POINTS_y)
PICTURE_BOX_2.Image = My_Bitmap
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.